# MAUI: How to bind Event Properties(sender, EventArgs) in code; binding to ViewModel or Code Behind

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, event-handling, maui, gesture-recognition

I have successfully bound a DrogGestureRecognizer's Drop event to the CodeBehind  using XAML markup as shown below:

```
<Label Text="MyTestItem" >
  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropGestureRecognizer_Drop_Item"/>
  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

However I need to accomplish the same thing in c# code as I am creating a view/control that must be dynamically built due to recursion. My requirement is that I get both the arguments from the event (sender and DropEventArgs).  I'm open to a solution that works with the CodeBehind or the ViewModel.

Below is my attempt, however I'm struggling with the MultiBinding. You can see my comments in the code:

```
RelativeBindingSource rbs2 = new   RelativeBindingSource(RelativeBindingSourceMode.FindAncestorBindingContext, ancestorType: typeof(TreeViewPageViewModel));

DropGestureRecognizer dropgGr = new DropGestureRecognizer { AllowDrop = true };

dropgGr.Bind(DropGestureRecognizer.DropCommandProperty,
    mode: BindingMode.OneTime,
    source: rbs2,
    path: "DropGestureRecognizerDropCommand"
);

dropgGr.SetBinding(DropGestureRecognizer.DropCommandParameterProperty, new MultiBinding
{
    Bindings = new Collection<BindingBase>
    {
        new Binding("."), // Is this the sender?
        new Binding("")   // How to set the DropEvenArgs here?  x:TypeArguments="DropEventArgs"
    }
});
label.GestureRecognizers.Add(dropgGr);
```

SOLVED:
The goal is to allow my control to drag and drop from one label to another label inside the control, not external desktop drag/drop integration. I have been able to attach a Flyout menu to my label and a TapGestureRecognizer and get it to successfully call a command in my ViewModel with the code below.

```
            RelativeBindingSource rbs = new RelativeBindingSource(RelativeBindingSourceMode.FindAncestorBindingContext, ancestorType: typeof(ITreeViewPageViewModel));

            // Context Menu --------------------------------------
            var menuItem1 = new MenuFlyoutItem
            {
                Text = "Delete Item",
                CommandParameter = xamlItem.ItemId
            };

            menuItem1.Bind(MenuFlyoutItem.CommandProperty,
                mode: BindingMode.OneTime,
                source: rbs,
                path: "DeleteItemCommand"
            );

            var menuFlyout = new MenuFlyout();

            menuFlyout.Add(menuItem1);
            FlyoutBase.SetContextFlyout(label, menuFlyout);

            // TagGesture ----------------------------------------
            TapGestureRecognizer tgr = new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Buttons = ButtonsMask.Primary,
                CommandParameter = xamlItem.ItemId,
                NumberOfTapsRequired = 2
            };
            tgr.Bind(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty,
                mode: BindingMode.OneTime,
                source: rbs,
                path: "ItemSelectedCommand"
                );

            label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);
```

In the above examples notice the commandParameter is being set, however in this case the parameter is an ID from my data.
What I really need for my DragDrop Gestures, is to attach to the existing Drop "event" rather than a "Command". It turns out it was surpisingly easy:

```
            DropGestureRecognizer dropGr = new DropGestureRecognizer { AllowDrop = true };
            dropGr.Drop += DropGr_Drop_Item; 
            label.GestureRecognizers.Add(dropGr);
        
        // This method is in the same class as the above code, and since I need to call a method in my
        // ViewModel you can see the last line that is used to accomplish this.
        private void DropGr_Drop_Item(object? sender, DropEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = e.Data.Properties["Text"].ToString();
            var sourceItemId = e.Data.Properties["ItemId"].ToString();


            var label = (sender as Element)?.Parent as Label;
            var targetItemId = label.StyleId.Substring(5);

            
            (this.BindingContext as ITreeViewPageViewModel).ReOrderItems(sourceItemId, targetItemId); 
   
        }
```

Comment: Why did you bind it from the code, and not directly from the xaml?

Comment: I'm creating a tree control that requires recursion and thus XAML is not sufficient. The entire control is done in c#.

Comment: If you build everything yourself, then you can instead build the Data to be pulled when the DragStart happens, and use that object to contain all you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#store-data-in-the-property-bag

Comment: Glad you solved it! Feel free to post an answer below to help others with similar questions.  By the way, if you want to invoke a Command through an Event , [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior) might also be helpful.

Comment: @o_w  You are correct that I should have put the <control:TreeView  /> tag in the XAML. That is a mistake I will fix, along with hopefully some item and folder templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I really needed for my DragDrop Gestures was to attach to the existing Drop "event" rather than a "Command". It turns out it was surpisingly easy:

```
    DropGestureRecognizer dropGr = new DropGestureRecognizer { AllowDrop = true };
            dropGr.Drop += DropGr_Drop_Item; 
            label.GestureRecognizers.Add(dropGr);
        
        // This method is in the same class as the above code, and since I need to call a method in my
        // ViewModel you can see the last line that is used to accomplish this.
        private void DropGr_Drop_Item(object? sender, DropEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = e.Data.Properties["Text"].ToString();
            var sourceItemId = e.Data.Properties["ItemId"].ToString();


            var label = (sender as Element)?.Parent as Label;
            var targetItemId = label.StyleId.Substring(5);

            
            (this.BindingContext as ITreeViewPageViewModel).ReOrderItems(sourceItemId, targetItemId); 
   
        }
```

Comment: Good job! Please consider accepting your answer which may help others with similar questions. Thanks for your sharing!